# pointer to QOpenGLWidget caused app crash while exiting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opengl, unhandled-exception

I found weird bug with `QOpenGLWidget` when it starts running on second monitor (maybe it's general for 'not main' monitor). If I run my app on main monitor/screen it works normally but if it run on second monitor it's crashes while closing. I removed as many code as possible to make SSCCE code which reproduce this issue (it is below) and btw I found possible reason but it doesn't make sense to me.

In main I have pointer to widget (it inherits upon `QOpenGLWidget`). App start normally, renders rgb triangle but when I try to close it, I receive:

`"Unhandled exception at 0x0000000067681C6A (Qt5Cored.dll) in QtTests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008."`.

If I declare it without 'new' (like usual object in scope) everything works perfect. It happens only when I have `QOpenGLWidget` inside (no matter how "deep"). I tested this with `QWidget`, `QMenuBar`, `QMenu`, `QAction`, `QToolBar`, `QPushButton`, `QTabWidget` and **even** `QGLWidge` and all is fine, it happens only for `QOpenGLWidget`. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong? Why I cannot use pointer to widget if it contains `QOpenGLWidget` inside?

```
file "main.cpp"
#include "qttest.hpp"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFontDatabase>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //this is not working
    OpenGLWidget* mainWindow; 
    mainWindow = new OpenGLWidget();
    mainWindow->show();

    //this is working
    //OpenGLWidget mainWindow;
    //mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

.

```
file "qttest.hpp"
#ifndef QTTEST_HPP
#define QTTEST_HPP
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>

class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit OpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
private:
signals :
    public slots :
};

#endif
```

.

```
file "openglwidget.cpp"
#include "qttest.hpp"

OpenGLWidget::OpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) {
    this->move(1800, 400); //set on main/other monitor
    this->resize(700, 300);
}

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClearColor(0.1875, 0.1875, 0.1875, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0);
    glEnd();
}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, (float)w / h, 0.01, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

If it can helps there is stacktrace from Visual Studio:

```
Qt5Cored.dll!QScopedPointer<QObjectData,QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::data() Line 141   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!qGetPtrHelper<QScopedPointer<QObjectData,QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> > >(const QScopedPointer<QObjectData,QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> > & p) Line 980    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::d_func() Line 116 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::thread() Line 1432    C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QOffscreenSurface::create() Line 183    C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QOffscreenSurface::setScreen(QScreen * newScreen) Line 328  C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QOffscreenSurface::screenDestroyed(QObject * object) Line 342   C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QOffscreenSurface::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a) Line 83 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaObject::activate(QObject * sender, int signalOffset, int local_signal_index, void * * argv) Line 3742 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaObject::activate(QObject * sender, const QMetaObject * m, int local_signal_index, void * * argv) Line 3603    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::destroyed(QObject * _t1) Line 214 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::~QObject() Line 923   C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QScreen::~QScreen() Line 139    C++
[External Code] 
Qt5Guid.dll!QPlatformIntegration::destroyScreen(QPlatformScreen * screen) Line 496  C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsIntegration::emitDestroyScreen(QPlatformScreen * s) Line 101  C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsScreenManager::clearScreens() Line 561    C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsContext::~QWindowsContext() Line 357  C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsIntegrationPrivate::~QWindowsIntegrationPrivate() Line 247    C++
[External Code] 
qwindowsd.dll!QScopedPointerDeleter<QWindowsIntegrationPrivate>::cleanup(QWindowsIntegrationPrivate * pointer) Line 60  C++
qwindowsd.dll!QScopedPointer<QWindowsIntegrationPrivate,QScopedPointerDeleter<QWindowsIntegrationPrivate> >::~QScopedPointer<QWindowsIntegrationPrivate,QScopedPointerDeleter<QWindowsIntegrationPrivate> >() Line 108  C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsIntegration::~QWindowsIntegration() Line 264  C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsGdiIntegration::~QWindowsGdiIntegration() Line 62 C++
[External Code] 
Qt5Guid.dll!QGuiApplicationPrivate::~QGuiApplicationPrivate() Line 1502 C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplicationPrivate::~QApplicationPrivate() Line 199    C++
[External Code] 
Qt5Cored.dll!QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData>::cleanup(QObjectData * pointer) Line 60 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QScopedPointer<QObjectData,QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::~QScopedPointer<QObjectData,QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >() Line 108   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::~QObject() Line 1049  C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::~QCoreApplication() Line 854 C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QGuiApplication::~QGuiApplication() Line 629    C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::~QApplication() Line 895  C++
QtTests.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 18   C++
QtTests.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, char * __formal, int __formal) Line 123 C++
[External Code]
```

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 Community with Qt add-in 1.2.5 and Qt 5.7 (msvc2013_64).

Comment: `mainWindow = new OpenGLWidget(mainWindow);` passing garbage as parent?

Comment: I forgot about that, that was my last desperate try. Anyway `mainWindow = new OpenGLWidget()` does not working too.

Comment: It's very strange that your backtrace is mising all the symbols... Don't you have PDB files for creating a complete backtrace?

Comment: Thank you for telling me that PDB files are so important I didn't realized they exist and might be so useful :) I pasted complete stacktrace.

Comment: I don't know if is it solved or not, but nobody handles deletion of that object. You should use a smart pointer here. I think this would be the difference to use a stack variable. From C++14 the following is preferred `const auto mainWindow = std::make_shared<OpenGLWidget>();`
( in C++11 you can use `const std::unique_ptr<OpenGLWidget>(new OpenGLWidget());`) Do not forget `#include <memory>`